# Shared probability function of dependent Poisson variable and Binomial variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The number of people that enter a shop is a Poisson variable with parameter $\lambda=50$. The probability that a customer that entered the shop will buy something is $p=0.16$.

I need to calculate the probability that:

1. exactly 20 customers, out of all the customers that entered the shop in 2 hours, will buy something
2. exactly 5 customers buy something if it is known that in 1 hour 40 customers entered the shop

---

1. 

let $X$ be the number of customers who buy something, and let $Y$ be the number of customers that entered the shop. The shared probability function $p(x, y)$ when $x=20$ is $$p(20, y)=e^{-100}\frac{100^y}{y!}\binom{y}{20}(0.16)^{20}{0.84}^{y-20}$$
hence the required probability is $$\sum_{y=20}^{\infty}e^{-100}\frac{100^y}{y!}\binom{y}{20}(0.16)^{20}{0.84}^{y-20}=\sum_{y=20}^{\infty}e^{-100}\frac{100^y}{y!}\frac{y!}{20!(y-20)!}(\frac{0.16}{0.84})^{20}{0.84}^y=\frac{e^{-100}}{20!}(\frac{0.16}{0.84})^{20}\sum_{y=20}^{\infty}\frac{100^y \cdot 0.84^y}{(y-20)!}=\frac{e^{-100}}{20!}(\frac{0.16}{0.84})^{20}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\frac{84^{y+20}}{y!}=\frac{e^{-100}}{20!}(16)^{20}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\frac{84^y}{y!}=\frac{e^{-100}}{20!}(16)^{20}e^{84}=\frac{e^{-16}}{20!}(16)^{20}\approx 0.0559$$

2.

$$P\{X=5|Y=40\}=\frac{P\{X=5, Y=40\} }{P\{Y=40\} } = \frac{e^{-50}\frac{50^{40}}{40!}\binom{40}{5}(0.16)^{5}{0.84}^{35}}{e^{-50}\frac{50^{40}}{40!}}=\binom{40}{5}(0.16)^{5}{0.84}^{35}\approx 0.1544$$

But I've a problem settling these results with what I understand, it appears, to me, in both answers that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, while I know that they aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, it is not necessary to appeal to the binomial distribution.  Instead, the random number of customers who buy something is itself Poisson with rate $\lambda p$, since this is a *thinned* Poisson process.  However, you do not specify the time increment for the original rate $\lambda = 50$.  Is it $50$ customers visiting per hour?  Per $2$ hours?  This information is absent; therefore, I will assume this is an hourly rate.

Then, with a slight modification of your notation, let $Y(t)$ represent the number of visiting customers in $t$ hours, and $X(t)$ represent the number of customers who buy something in $t$ hours.  As I mentioned above, $$X(t) \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda p t = 8t),$$ consequently $$\Pr[X(2) = 20] = e^{-16} \frac{(16)^{20}}{20!} \approx 0.0559195.$$  Your solution basically goes through a proof that the marginal (unconditional) distribution $X(t)$ is Poisson when the conditional random variable $X(t) \mid Y(t)$ is binomial and $Y(t)$ is Poisson; i.e., your solution actually proves the Poisson thinning property for the specific numeric case you are considering.

For the second question, $$X(1) \mid Y(1) = 40 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 40, p = 0.16),$$ therefore $$\Pr[X(1) = 5 \mid Y(1) = 40] = \binom{40}{5} (0.16)^5 (1 - 0.16)^{40 - 5} \approx 0.154385.$$

Comment: Good answer (thinning is always appreciated), but I am not sure it actually answers the question asked originally; same for my own answer...

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be the number of people that entered the shop, and let $X$ be the number of people who further bought something.

You know:

- $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$.
- $X = \sum_{i=1}^Y Z_i$, where $(Z_i)$ are independent of $Y$ and iid with distribution $P(Z_i = 1) = 1 - P(Z_i = 0) = p$.

In other words, given $Y = y$, X follows a $\text{Bin}(y,p)$-distribution.

The simultaneous probability function $p(x,y)$ may be written as
$$
p(x,y) = P(X = x \, | \, Y = y) \cdot P(Y = y)
$$
for $(x,y) \in \{(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}_0 : n\leq m\}$. (It is zero otherwise.) By inserting the relevant marginal and conditional distribution, one arrives at your expression.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: To further elaborate, the two random variables are clearly not independent: But you may always form the simultaenous distribution by multiplying not the marginal distributions but the conditional and marginal distributions.